# Localization in Angular2 using Angular-cli

Tags: angular, localization, angular-cli

Is there a tool for localization in Angular **2** when using **Angular-cli**?

I ran into [this link](https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/11/03/angular2-and-i18n-translate-your-app/) (from November) stating that "right now, you can’t use the CLI in translated applications" so the i18n tool can't be used in my application.

Is there another way to translate the application to different languages?

(I'm using webpack, not systemJs)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

Comment: Good link @R.Richards also, here is a CLI specific link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-internationalization

Comment: https://github.com/angular-pakistan/ng-conf-2017. Look for "Lost in Translation"

Comment: @Brocco that works. Thanks!

Comment: @cookya Glad that helped, I put that link with some details as an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a story in the Angular CLI wiki which should help you:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-internationalization

From that article:

> When your app is ready, you can extract the strings to translate from your templates with the ng xi18n command.

```
ng xi18n --output-path src/locale
```

Once you've translated you can serve:

```
ng serve --aot --locale fr --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.fr.xlf
```

Or build:

```
ng build --aot --locale fr --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf
```