# Angular CLI with i18n localization (XMB file)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there any complete example for default i18n localization using latest angular cli? I proceeded as follows:

1. `ng new <project>`
2. `cd <project>`
   `ng build -prod` OK
3. update app.component.html with this i18n attribute in h1 tag:
   `<h1 i18n="site header|An introduction header@@header">
   Welcome to {{title}}!
   </h1>`
4. extract i18n with command:
   `ng xi18n --locale en --output-path localize -xmb --out-file msg.en.xmb` OK
5. create copy of `msg.en.xmb` as `msg.sk.xmb`
6. modify text in `msg.sk.xmb` to "Ahoj"
   `<messagebundle>
   <msg id="header" desc="An introduction header" meaning="site header"><source>app\app.component.ts:3,5</source>
   Ahoj <ph name="INTERPOLATION"><ex>INTERPOLATION</ex></ph>!
   </msg>
   </messagebundle>`
7. **??? what to do now?**

**I tried:**

A) what I expected `ng serve --locale sk --i18n-format xmb --i18n-file localize/msg.sk.xmb`
RESULT: No error, after go to localhost text is not changed: Welcome to app!

B) full path: `ng serve --locale sk --i18n-format xmb --i18n-file c:\Angular\project\localize\msg.sk.xmb`
RESULT as in A) no error, nothing happend.

C) other, like generate build for production (any build with `--aot` or build for `-prod` finish with an error: `Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'...`)

Also checked this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-internationalization and this answer [Localization in Angular2 using Angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763371/localization-in-angular2-using-angular-cli) (but there is no exact steps how to get it work with XMB file).

**How to finish translation in xmb files and use it for serve / build translated app?** Can you recommend me the commands from step 7?

My versions (latest for 2017-07-24): `@angular/cli: 1.2.4, node: 8.2.1, os: win32 x64`

Comment: according to [this article](https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358) the correct syntax is `ng serve --aot --i18n-format=xmb --i18n-file=localize/msg.sk.xmb --locale=sk` but I can't get it to work right now because of [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4551)

Comment: Reported directly as bug here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7133